# Sencha onReady() function

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-architect

I am very new to Sencha.

Now I am using Sencha architect to develop my application. To add a functionality I am using an opensource extension in my application. The documentation for the extension tells to add piece of code to the onReady() function. But I am stuck here because I am not able to find the onReady() function in my Application.

The question is where to find the onReady() function in a Sencha application while using Sencha Architect 3.0.2?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried?

Comment: It's equivalent to the launch method in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the application launch function.  Select Application and click the plus next to launch.  Add your code in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 

// code 

} )
```

Reference: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246408-Where-to-add-onReady-function-in-Sencha-Architect-2